# Can you install a standalone TFS client that doesn't need Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Is it possible to get a standalone TFS client on a server that does NOT have Visual Studio installed?  We'd like a way to "reach into" a TFS project from a server, without having to install Visual Studio?

Possible?  I've seen Team Explorer, but will that work without Visual Studio?

Comment: May be helpful: [Team Explorer without Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666371/does-the-free-team-explorer-client-work-without-visual-studio), and [Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915995/visual-studio-2010-team-explorer)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Team Explorer 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181475.aspx) will allow you to connect to TFS, but it will install a Visual Studio shell.

[Team Explorer Everywhere](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/team-explorer-everywhere-vs.aspx) has Web access.  [Martin Woodward](http://www.woodwardweb.com/teamprise/goodbye_teampri.html) wrote a great article about it.

Comment: "Team Explorer Everywhere" link is 404 Not Found.

Answer (score 20):

Download [the TFS power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f).  The "Windows Shell Extension" component allows one to perform most operations with TFS via Windows Explorer.  Note that the Power Tools installer states that Visual Studio 2010 (or Visual Studio Team Explorer 2010) is a prerequisite for the following features:

- Command-line interface
- Visual Studio Integration
- Check-in Policy Pack
- Process Editor
- Windows Shell Extension
- PowerShell Cmdlets

Comment: I'm looking at the TS power tools installer and it says that VS 2010 is required for these features (and others): CLI, windows shell extension, powershell cmdlets

Answer (score 16):

It's 2017 and Microsoft (re)introduced the standalone Team Explorer.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2017/04/05/reintroducing-the-team-explorer-standalone-installer/

> If you remember back to 2013 (and before), we released standalone installers for Team Explorer. In VS 2015, we did not release a standalone Team Explorer since customers had free options with Express SKUs and Community, which included Team Explorer functionality.
>
> Customers have continued to request a standalone installer for Team Explorer for non-developers, however. And so today, with the Visual Studio 2017 Update release, the standalone Team Explorer installer is back.

Download - https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=TeamExplorer&rel=15

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15876444)

Comment: The essential part is the official TFS client tool, which is kind of hard to include in other ways than a download link. Base64? ;)

Answer (score 12):

Included with Team Foundation Server there is a free web front end called "TFS Web Access". In TFS 2008, the Web Access was a different installation and it came as a Power Tool to the TFS. In TFS 2010, the Web Access is installed automatically and is part of the TFS.

In order to get to the Web Access in TFS 2010 do the following:

In your preferred browser type:

http://[YourServerName]:8080/tfs/web/

YourServerName is the tfs name for example: http://tfs-srv:8080/tfs/web/

Also, if you need Agile planning and a Task Board with TFS Web Access, take a look at Urban Turtle - http://urbanturtle.com. According to Microsoft, this is the premier Scrum tooling for TFS.

Discloser: I work with the Urban Turtle team. So do not take my words. Instead, read what Microsoft blogs said about Urban Turtle.
http://blogs.msdn.com/search/SearchResults.aspx?q=urban%20turtle&sections=3652.

Comment: I had never noticed the **EDIT button in tfs web** before. This is exactly the lightweight editor I was looking for =)

Answer (score 3):

There now seems to be a more generic [Team Explorer Everywhere for TFS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30661) - perhaps that will give us non-VS users desktop access to TFS :)

It includes an Eclipse plug-in and usefully, a command line client.

Comment: Nope.  Team Explorer Everywhere is a plug-in to Eclipse.  If you want a standalone Team Explorer, install the standalone Team Explorer.

Comment: Clarified answer to mention there is a command line client too. Thanks.

Comment: But we include a command line with the normal Team Explorer!  Seriously, Team Explorer Everywhere is really designed for Eclipse users and cross-platform developers, it's not even officially supported on Windows!

Comment: Oh, is Team Explorer standalone from VS? Will look into it - thanks.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I presume you don't mean Team Explorer for Visual Studio ... http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30656 as its the VS install we are trying to avoid...

Comment: If you install it standalone, it will install into a bare VS shell which is not, in fact, Visual Studio, as the accepted answer points out.  If that's truly unacceptable, then by all means, use TEE.

Comment: @EdwardThomson yes - but to get the command line tool you need to download and install, well, a rather large client.  I never intend to use the GUI - I'm trying to checkin/out via a script.  So why do I need to install TE on a server?

Answer (score 0):

While it appears to be a dead project. If you like having version control outside an IDE (or independant of the IDE). There is SVN Bridge, which allows you to use TortoiseSVN to talk to your TFS server.

https://svnbridge.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can install **Team Explorer** (on the TFS install DVD, or you can download it from MSDN) without needing to have VS2010 installed - Team Explorer will install a 'shell' VS2010 with only the TFS features available - none of the IDE components.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=fe4f9904-0480-4c9d-a264-02fedd78ab38