# TFS source control without Visual Studio?

Tags: tfs, team-explorer, source-control-explorer

Is it possible to use TFS source control without Visual Studio? I have to put some files in some source control, those files are stored in a folder in some server, that is something developed in Oracle forms. I just need to add those files in some source control and I'd like to use TFS for that. Any tips or tools could we use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am one of the lovers of TFS, but I think in your case if you don't need to use Team Explorer or Team Explorer Everywhere (which will need command line used) for none windows I suggest to use SVN sub version (VisualSVN Server) it's open source and it has integrated OS shell (TortoiseSVN ) right click menu which will be easy than using command line

Answer (score 8):

TFS is likely to be overkill for a few files in a single folder, but if the TFS infrastructure is already in place then it will work.

You will need Team Explorer (or, on non-Windows) Team Explorer Everywhere installed to give you the client tools. But you can perform all source code operations with the [`tf.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0.aspx) command line (or equivalent from Team Explorer Everywhere).

Answer (score 7):

[Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f/) has Windows Shell Extensions that provides integration 
 with Windows Explorer and the common file dialogs.  With this integration, you can perform many source control operations without having to run Visual Studio or a Team Foundation command-line tool.

Comment: I downloaded it but how do I use it now? I only see "Best Practices Analyzer" entry in the menu.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge first create a local workspace and map it to a project on the TFS server. Then from within Windows Explorer each file icon will have a little green arrow in the bottom left corner to indicate it's in source control. Right-click a file and see the Team Foundation Server pop-out menu to see the available actions.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthc5x3f(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380955/can-you-install-a-standalone-tfs-client-that-doesnt-need-visual-studio/4380996#4380996) but you will need to make sure you have tfs server running as well to connect to.  Would it not be simpler to use git/mercurial/svn...{any other free source control system}?

Answer (score 0):

Vlad: That is true, but this important:  I have used the "Shell Extensions" for a while only to realize that it does create problems.  First of all, the "Shell Extensions" does not report errors during a check-in; it only unexpectedly stops, and the window closes.

Also, the reason I am looking for an external "Source Control Explorer" is that if you delete any file from Window Explorer that was under Source Control by TFS, the Check-In procedure will fail saying that there is a file missing.  The correct way to safely delete a file is to do it through "Source Control Explorer"; the check-in then works.  Usually not a problem, unless, like me, you have a Java project and have no integration between NetBeans & TFS.