# Do we still require separate licence for TeamExplorer as Standalone client if already have vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, licensing, client

We have Visual Studio 2010 premium edition on our systems and Can succesfully use Team Explorer build in it. But I want to use Team explorer separatly. How can I install it separatly without installing VS2010 on some user machines or can we separate vs2010 and team explorer if already installed. Also Do I still need to have separate licence for this per user. I know we have Team web access but need team explorer independently.

Please guide.

I have read the following posts but still not clear:

- [Standalone GUI client for TFS 2010 Source Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882636/standalone-gui-client-for-tfs-2010-source-control)
- [Does the free Team Explorer client work without Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666371/does-the-free-team-explorer-client-work-without-visual-studio)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a TFS Client Access License (CAL) for these users, then you can use the standalone Team Explorer at no [additional](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/vstsstart/thread/63c76fbc-4c8c-481e-9481-3793cadd3103) [cost](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/91bb1fcd-7d8f-4210-baa4-cdc7661271ac).

You should already have a CAL for those users if they're using TFS Web Access, so yes, they should be able to use the standalone Team Explorer.